# How do I stop duplicate mailings from being sent out?

Tags: civimail

We are having problems with duplicate mailings being sent out. John Doe may be listed more then once in CiviCRM - For example, **John Doe** and **Doe, John** but it's the same addressee. What can I do to rectify the matter so that only one mailing will go out to this addressee versus two?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should eliminate the duplication in your database. The CRM provides a [tool for handling the duplicated contacts](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/). You can merge the duplicated contacts into a single one. With this the email addresses will be unique so that only one email will be sent.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will that apply to mail as well? It's not emails, it's actual duplicate mailings being sent to contacts' address in CiviCRM.

Comment: Sure. You might need to create a custom ruleset for the address fields, and you can run it manually. Info about the rule configuration: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#configuring-rules Manual execution: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/#using-rules-and-merging-duplicate-contacts-manually

Comment: How are you creating the mailings?

If you run a search to find contacts in a specific group, the actions list gives you the "Mailing Labels- Print" action.
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/postal-mail-communications/

And from here there are further address merge tools- but these will only work where contacts share an address,
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/contacts/#addresses